# Laravel 4 typeahead

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-4

Is it possible to make a typeahead with a Laravel model?
something like:

```
        <input type="text" class="span3" style="margin: 0 auto;" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="1"
   data-source='["User::all()"]'>
```

If it is, could you provide some little tutorial or clarify?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$users=User::all()` returns an object, may be you need to convert it to an array, you can try something like `$udata=array();foreach($users as $user)array_push($udata,$user->name);endforeach` pass `$udata`it to your view and then in your view `data-source='{{$udata}}'`

Comment: thats not possible, did you put `<input type="text" class="span3" style="margin: 0 auto;" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="1" data-source='<?print_r($udata);?>'>` in your view file?

Comment: try this I have updated `data-source part` http://paste.laravel.com/Ida

Answer (score 1):

Use the Blade templating engine for this for this.

**UserController.php**

```
/* ... */
public function getUsers() 
{
    $users = User::all(array('name'));
    return View::make('users.show')->with('users', $users);
}
```

**show.blade.php**

```
<input type="text" class="span3" style="margin: 0 auto;" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="1" data-source='{{ json_encode($users) }}'>
```

Comment: I don't think this will work, as $users is an object and typeahead needs either an array or function. BTW `with()` doesn't accepts double arrow

Comment: @JanP.
Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work. I get some kind of grammar error: `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::columnize() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\Users\E1\Desktop\laravel-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php on line 111 and defined`

Comment: @JanP.
it doesn't have any errors, but still it doesn't typeahead the names.. I've got the typeahead.js and everything.. but it doesn't display the names.

Comment: @erm_durr what is in the `data-source=` field in the view after rendering?

Comment: @TryingTobemyself
`<input type="text" class="span3" style="margin: 0 auto;" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="1" data-source='{}'>`

Comment: @erm_durr try what i have commented on your question above

Comment: @TryingTobemyself still no typeahead.. here's what the source is displaying:  `<input type="text" class="span3" style="margin: 0 auto;" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="1" data-source='<?print_r($udata);?>'>`